# Surface Area by Integration

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, surface-integrals

$$2\pi\int_{3}^6\left(\frac{1}{3}x^\frac{3}{2}-x^\frac{1}{2}\right)\left(1+\left(\frac{1}{2}x^\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{2}x^\frac{-1}{2}\right)^2\right)^\frac{1}{2}dx$$

I've managed to simplify this down to the equation below (not sure if it'll help), but I still can't integrate it.

Please help.

$$\frac{\pi}{3}\int_{3}^6(x^4-4x^3-2x^2+12x+9)^\frac{1}{2}dx$$

PS. The answer you should get is 9$\pi$.

Answer (score 1):

You did a good bit of the hard work yourself, but these other computations may help:
\begin{align}
\frac{\pi}{3}\int_3^6\sqrt{x^4-4x^3-2x^2+12x+9}\;dx &= \frac{\pi}{3}\int_3^6 (x^2-2x-3)\;dx\tag{simplify}\\[1em]
                  &= \frac{\pi}{3}\int_3^6 x^2\;dx - \frac{2\pi}{3}\int_3^6x\;dx -\pi\int_3^61\;dx\\[1em]
                  &= \left.\frac{\pi x^3}{9}\right|_3^6-\frac{2\pi}{3}\int_3^6x\;dx-\pi\int_3^61\;dx\tag{FTC}\\[1em]
                  &= 21\pi-\frac{2\pi}{3}\int_3^6x\;dx-\pi\int_3^61\;dx\\[1em]
                  &= 21\pi+\left.\left(-\frac{\pi x^2}{3}\right)\right|_3^6-\pi\int_3^61\;dx\tag{FTC}\\[1em]
                  &= 12\pi-\pi\int_3^61\;dx\\[1em]
                  &= 12\pi+\left.(-\pi x)\right|_3^6\\[1em]
                  &= 9\pi.
\end{align}
Hence, you can see the integral evaluates to $9\pi$, as desired.

Answer (score 0):

HINT

I would say

$x^4-4x^3-2x^2+12x+9=(x^2-2x-3)^2$

Comment: Thanks, this does lead to the correct answer, but how did you know that?

Comment: @Ahmed Have you ever heard of synthetic division?

Comment: @induktio No, what is it?

Comment: @Ahmed It's a way of factoring polynomials. Watch this: https://www.khanacademy.org/math/algebra2/polynomial_and_rational/synthetic-division/v/synthetic-division

Comment: @Ahmed  Such a possibility, I kind of expected. So I tried to guess (substituting in the equation) simple roots. I guessed double root x = -1, and it was.